# Range Subequation numbers like (1a-z) instaed of 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, 1e, .....1z

Tags: equations, numbering, arrays, subequations

[image]

```
\begin{subequations}
        %\begin{flalign}
        \begin{eqnarray}
        _{\mathrm L}\mathbf{M}
        \equiv 
        \left\[
        \begin{array}{ccc}
        _{\mathrm L}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm f}_{ii}& 0 & 0 \vspace{.5em} \\
        0 & _{\mathrm L}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm fs}_{cc} & 0 \vspace{.5em} \\
        0 & 0 &_{\mathrm L}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm s}_{ii}  \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\],\label{fsi_mass_mat}\\
        \mathbf{C}
        \equiv 
        \left\[
        \begin{array}{ccc}
        \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm f}_{ii}& \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm f}_{ic} & 0 \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm f}_{ci}&\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm f}_{cc} & 0 \vspace{.5em} \\
        0 & 0 &\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm s}_{ii}  \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\],\label{fsi_diffusion_mat} \\
        \mathbf{G}
        \equiv 
        \left\[
        \begin{array}{c}
        \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm f}_{i} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm f}_{c} \vspace{.5em} \\
        0 \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\],\label{fsi_divergence_mat} \\
        \mathbf{q(u)}
        \equiv 
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{c}
        0 \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm s}_{c}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm s) \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm s}_{i}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm s) \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\},\label{fsi_internal_force_vec_str}\\
        \mathbf{N}
        \equiv 
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{c}
        \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm f}_{i} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm f}_{c} \vspace{.5em} \\
        0 \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\},\label{fsi_convection_vec} \\
        \mathbf{g}
        \equiv 
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{c}
        \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm f}_{i} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm fs}_{c} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm s}_{i} \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\},\label{fsi_external_force_vec} \\
        \mathbf{a}
        \equiv 
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{c}
        \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm f}_{i} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm fs}_{c} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm s}_{i} \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\},\label{fsi_accl_vec} \\
        \mathbf{v}
        \equiv 
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{c}
        \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm f}_{i} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm fs}_{c} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm s}_{i} \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\},\label{fsi_vel_vec} \\
        \mathbf{u}
        \equiv 
        \left\{
        \begin{array}{c}
        \ast \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm fs}_{c} \vspace{.5em} \\
        \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm s}_{i} \vspace{.5em}
        \end{array}
        \right\},\label{fsi_disp_vec} 
        \end{eqnarray}
        %\end{flalign}
        \end{subequations}
```

I am trying to number these subequations from 4.45 (a), 4.45 (b), 4.45 (c), 4.45 (d), 4.45 (e),....4.45 (i) to 4.45 (a--i).
Kindly help me. Also, I want to force left align only these equations.
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure about your aim: do you want a single number 4.45(a-i)? If so, where should it be placed? And how would the reader know what's 4.45f without counting with their finger?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your quick response. Yes, I want a single number at the end of this subequation system. Also, I wish to force align to the left side. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, what's the reason for “a-i”?

Comment: Aside: The three instances of `\left\[` and `\right\]` cannot possibly work. Did you maybe mean to write `\left\{` and `\right\}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @egreg has already pointed out in a comment, it's not very reader-friendly to provide a single call-out of the form "(4.45a-i)" at the end of the group of nine [9!] subequations. In fact, some readers may get rather annoyed if you do this. I certainly would become annoyed if I had to spend more than a fraction of second to decide if one of the subequations somewhere in the middle of the list of subequations might be "4.45e" or "4.45f".

In contrast, it makes eminent sense to create a compressed cross-reference to a *range* of sub-equations. This can be done with the help of the `cleveref` package and its `\crefrangestripprefix` macro. See section 9, entitled "Advance cross-reference formating",  of the package's user guide for more information on this subject.

To *really impress* your readers as well as to make the code much easier to read -- and debug, if and when needed -- you should avail yourself of the facilities of the `amsmath` package -- such as the `bmatrix` and `Bmatrix` environments, instead of using lots of low-level `array` environments. Also, instead of providing 27 separate `\vspace{.5em}` instructions, simply reset the parameter `\arraystretch` to a value such as `1.33`. For sure, do *not* use the obsolete `eqnarray` environment. Instead, use an `align` or `flalign` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{subequation}{(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}#2#6)}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}\setcounter{equation}{44} % just for this example

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33} % or some other suitable value
\begin{flalign}
{}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M} &\equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      {}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ii} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & {}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 &{}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{s}}_{ii} \, 
   \end{bmatrix}, \label{fsi_mass_mat}\\
\mathbf{C} &\equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ii} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ic} & 0 \\
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ci} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{s}}_{ii} \,
   \end{bmatrix},\label{fsi_diffusion_mat} \\
\mathbf{G} &\equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{bmatrix}, \label{fsi_divergence_mat} \\
\mathbf{q(u)} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      0 \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{s}}_{c}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s}) \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s})
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_internal_force_vec_str}\\
\mathbf{N} &\equiv
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_convection_vec} \\
\mathbf{g} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i}  \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_external_force_vec} \\
\mathbf{a} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_accl_vec} \\
\mathbf{v} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_vel_vec} \\
\mathbf{u} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \ast \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i}
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_disp_vec} 
\end{flalign}
\end{subequations}

%% Generate a cross-reference to the full range of subequations
\Crefrange{fsi_mass_mat}{fsi_disp_vec} show that \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Although I could not get the numbering as I wanted, it is now much better than before.

Comment: @Prakash - You're most welcome!

Comment: @Mico- I attached a new figure of subequation system. Please have a look, If you know how to get this type of configuration then please help me. Thank you again

Comment: @Prakash - Since the new, four-row, system of 11 subequations is substantially different from the system shown in your original query, I would like to suggest that you post a *new query* to ask how the new look might be achieved. For sure, please don't edit other people's answers; instead, if you must, edit your own query. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico- Thank you. I just posted a new query and Taged you as-well. Please have a look and kindly help me. Sincerely, Prakasha.

Comment: @Mico- The query name is "Numbering of the Subequations"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you seek

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:labelequation}
\begin{equation}
    x=x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    y=y
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    z=z
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

See equations \eqref{eq:labelequation} 

\end{document}
```

[image]